# Constructor two classes up java

Tags: java, constructor

I am trying to access a constructor in an abstract class that is two levels higher.

```
    public abstract class Person{
        protected String name;

    public Person(String name){
         if name.length() <= 12)
            this.name = name;
         else 
            this.name = name.substring(0,12);
    }

    public final String returnName(){
       return name;
    }
   }

public class employee extends person{

        public employee(string firstname, string gender){
               super(firstname);
               this.gender =gender;
         }

}

public class dependent extends employee{

        public dependent(string firstname, string gender, string relation){
             super(firstname);
             super(gender);
             this.relation = relation;
        }
```

How do I invoke the constructor of the abstract class from the dependent class (two levels below)?

Comment: your code will not even compile try it again. it wont even compile.

Comment: `public abstract Person class` - what?

Comment: You don't have a constructor for super(gender) it would be super (firstname,gender)

Comment: This has been asked before.  You can't skip the "in between" class - you have to call one of the constructors of `employee` from within `dependent`.  Fortunately, there is a suitable one there for you, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class employee extends Person{

        public employee(String firstname, String gender){
               super(firstname);
               this.gender =gender;
         }

}

public class dependent extends employee{

        public dependent(String firstname, String gender, String relation){
             super(firstname,gender);
             this.relation = relation;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, here's how you pass two parameters to your Employee constructor:

```
super(firstname, gender);
```

Second, there's no need to call the Person constructor from the Dependent one. This will happen automatically when Dependent calls the Employee constructor, because the Employee constructor then calls the Person one.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is something like the below, please note Classes start with Upper-case and camel case for method parameter staring with a lower-case letter. String must be upper-case `String name` , please also be aware you have introduced a protected member scope on `name`
See the following post on the implications [In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

```
  public abstract class Person
  {
    protected String name;

    public Person(String name)
    {
      if (name.length() <= 12)
      {
        this.name = name;
      }
      else
      {
        this.name = name.substring(0, 12);
      }
    }

    public final String returnName()
    {
      return name;
    }
  }

  public class Employee extends Person
  {
    private String gender = null;

    public Employee(String firstName, String gender)
    {
      super(firstName);
      this.gender = gender;
    }

  }

  public class Dependent extends Employee
  {
    private String relation = null;

    public Dependent(String firstName, String gender, String relation)
    {
      super(firstName, gender);
      this.relation = relation;
    }
  }
```

You will need to add methods to access the relation and gender if you need the access to these